# Teleporting random walk

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

Given a directed graph $G = (V,E)$, to define a random walk on $G$ with a transition probability matrix $P$ such that it has a unique stationary distribution (as mentioned in [this paper](http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2005/papers/131_LabeledUnlabeledGraph_ZhouEtAl.pdf))
I used a one step teleporting random walk (also mentioned in the paper) to obtain the transition probability matrix from the matrix $W$ (matrix of weights of edges). So if there is any edge outs from the current vertex ($u$), and if $d$ is the probability of jumping uniformly to any vertex of the graph, then $u$ jumps to other nodes with the total probability (with $(1-d)$) jumps randomly to any other vertex and with probability $d*(W(u,v)/dp(u))$ jumps to a vertex $v$ adjacent to it): $$(1-d)*1/n+d*(W(u,v)/dp(u))$$ where $dp$ is the outdegree edges from vertex $u$ and $v$ is any node jumps to it from $u$.  If there is no edge outs from $u$, the jump is from $u$ to any other node uniformly with probability $1/n$ . So, I obtain the transition matrix easily by this equation. Is it correct or the transition matrix must be obtained in recursive process and I do only one step of it?

Comment: Ooo, :) It seems to be correct and it works and the results were very nice.I maybe answer my question in this week in details because first I must learn Mathjex for equations.

Comment: @Byron thanks for edit.

Comment: It's pretty common; the word "probablity" appears over 60 times on this site. It's almost as bad as "continous", one of my pet peeves.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland You are right. I must improve my English.

Comment: Bad spelling affects native English speakers too.